# Outlook 2016 Add-in Dialog Height and Width Swapped

Tags: outlook, outlook-addin, office-js, outlook-web-addins, outlook-2016

I’m working on an add-in for Microsoft Outlook. Since the August 1 update of Outlook 2016 (Version 1807, Build 10325.20082), we have seen that dialogs that are being opened with `displayDialogAsync()` are displaying incorrectly (see code sample below). They are displaying wider and shorter than before. Upon trying to fix this, we realized that when we increased the height parameter, the dialog appeared really wide, and increasing the width parameter caused the dialog to appear really tall. We see that dialogs from other add-ins are also appearing shorter and wider. We suspect that the height and width parameters are being read incorrectly.

```
Office.context.ui.displayDialogAsync(dialogURL, {
     height: 60,
     width: 33,
     displayInIframe: true,
   }, dialogCallback);
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a known problem in some builds of Outlook 2016 including the build you have. It has been fixed in build 16.0.10713.10000 and later builds.